# when i add caffe Prebuilt binaries to my project a lot of error occurred

Tags: visual-c++, deep-learning, caffe

i download caffe prebuilt binaries from : https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows

create project property sheet for add caffe in my project :

```
AdditionalIncludeDirectories = D:\caffe_2\include;
AdditionalLibraryDirectories = D:\caffe_2\lib;
AdditionalDependencies = caffe.lib;proto.lib;
```

and write simple code to test caffe like this :

```
#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>

using namespace caffe;

void main() {
    Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::Brew::CPU);
}
```

but when i want build project a lot of error occur:

[image]

how can i add caffe to my project?

Comment: it seems like you are missing dependencies like `gflags`, `boost` etc.

Comment: can you tell me all dependencies caffe need?

Comment: look at the installation webpage there should be a list